# remove fuzzy entries from django.po file?

Tags: django, internationalization, locale, fuzzy-logic

How to remove all fuzzy entries from django.po files? When i run makemessage command it created lot of fuzzy files. Any  solution?

Answer (score 1):

Gettext [msgattrib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgattrib-Invocation.html) is your friend.

Comment: `ls **/*.po | xargs -n 1 -I @ msgattrib @ -o @` does work well. (`ls **/*.po ` is a function in zsh)

Answer (score 0):

Have your translators verify that the translations for those entries are still correct and remove the fuzzy flag.

Comment: why fuzzy flag created in django.po file?

Comment: The I18N'ed string no longer matches exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can search and replace using this regex `^#(\||,).*$` replace row found by empty. Then rerun the `django-admin makemessages` command.